# Proof that a projection minimizes the norm of error

Tags: inner-products

I'm trying to prove given a vector $\mathbf{x}$ that's an element of $\mathbb{C}^N$, the vector $\hat{x}$ defined as
$$\hat{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle \mathbf{s}^{(k)}\mathbf{x}\rangle\mathbf{s}^{(k)}$$
where $\{\mathbf{s}^{(k)}\}_{0}^{K-1}$ is an orthonormal basis for the subspace S satisfies $\text{arg min}_{\mathbf{y}\in S}(||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||)=\hat{x}$.

The inner product definition I'm using is $$\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x^{*}_ny_n$$

The first idea I had was simply expanding
$||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}||^2$, since minimizing $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}||^2$ is equalivalent to minimizing$||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}||$ for an arbitrary $\mathbf{p}$. $$||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}||^2=\langle \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p} \rangle=\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle-\text{Re}(\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{p}\rangle)+\langle \mathbf{p},\mathbf{p} \rangle$$

But I'm not sure how to go from here. I also tried writing $\mathbf{p}=\hat{\mathbf{x}}+\mathbf{d}$ to try and use $\langle \mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}},\hat{\mathbf{x}}\rangle=0$ which gave
$$||\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{d}||^2=\langle\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{d},\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{d}\rangle=\langle\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}},\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{d}\rangle-\langle \mathbf{d},\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{d}\rangle=\langle\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}},\mathbf{x}\rangle-\langle \mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}},\hat{\mathbf{x}}\rangle-\langle\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}},\mathbf{d}\rangle-\langle \mathbf{d},\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}\rangle+\langle \mathbf{d},\mathbf{d}\rangle=\langle \mathbf{d},\mathbf{d}\rangle+\langle \mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}},\mathbf{x}\rangle-2\text{Re}(\langle \mathbf{d}, \mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}\rangle)$$
Which doesn't seem to help either. The last thing I can think of is expressing the norm in terms of some parameter and differentiating and using that to find the minimum, but I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Any hints/answers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think the basis $\{s^{(k)}\}$ needs to be orthonormal for this to be true.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that, I'll edit the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that for arbitrary $y \in S$
$$\langle x - \hat{x},y - \hat{x} \rangle= \langle x,y \rangle - \langle x,\hat{x} \rangle-\langle \hat{x},y \rangle + \|\hat{x}\|^2$$

$$\langle x,y \rangle=\bigg\langle x ,\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle y,s^{(k)}\rangle s^{(k)}\bigg\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle y,s^{(k)}\rangle^*\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle $$

$$\langle x,\hat{x} \rangle= \bigg\langle x ,\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle s^{(k)}\bigg\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle^*\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle$$

$$\langle \hat{x},y \rangle= \bigg\langle \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle s^{(k)}, \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle y,s^{(k)}\rangle s^{(k)}\bigg\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle y,s^{(k)}\rangle^*\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle$$

$$\|\hat{x}\|^2=\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}|\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle|^2=\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle^*\langle x,s^{(k)}\rangle$$

So $\langle x - \hat{x},y - \hat{x} \rangle = 0$. This implies that $\hat{x}$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $S$, so
$$\|x-\hat{x}\|=\inf_{w \in S}\|x-w\|$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand that $\hat{x}$ is the orthogonal projection, I just don't understand why this guarantees that $||x-\hat{x}||$ is minimized. Intuitively I have the idea of a 3-dimensional vector projected onto a 2-d plane, but I'm not sure how to make this argument formal/rigorous.

Comment: @ParadoxicalPotato it's the definition of orthogonal projection.. your question asked if $\hat{x}$, as defined above, is the orthogonal projection of $x$ (i.e. that unique minimizer) and I formally showed it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the definition of orthogonal projections- thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome @ParadoxicalPotato